# Adjust an items Column via binding

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, grid

I am programming a calendar in Windows 8.1 using C#/XAML as well as the MVVM-Light Toolkit.

I have created an ItemsControl with a Grid as ItemsPanel so that I (hopefully - I haven't tried this yet) can place the items wherever I want inside that grid.

However that Grid has 3 fixed columns and I wanted to be able to determine which column to put the Item in by changing a property of that item.
I tried this by using bindings but this somehow does not work as expected - it only works with static numbers.

Here is the code that creates the list:

```
ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<object>(tmpPeriodsList.Select((x, i) => new
    {
        ColorHash = x.ColorHash,
        Index = i,
        Margin = new Thickness(0,60*i,0, 0),
        ColumnIndex = ColumnIndex(i),
    }));
}


private int ColumnIndex(int i)
{
    //Purpose: Place the third item the third column
    if (i == 2) return 2;
    return 0;
}
```

And here the XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Day.ItemsList, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">                     
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>                                 
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Those Bindings work fine -->
                <Grid Height="20" Width="80" Margin="{Binding Margin}">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ColorHash, Converter={StaticResource HexToColorConverter}}"/>
                </Grid.Background>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
            <!-- This line only works with static numbers (0,1,2) and 
                 changes the Column of all Elements -->
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle> 
</ItemsControl>
```

I am now guessing that Grid.Column is not of type integer. Such as the Width of a Column is not a double. May that be true?

I really don't have a clue what could be wrong there...

Thank you very much for your help!

FunkyPeanut

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your code somewhat for testing purposes and the binding works, the bound item is either in column 0 or column 2;

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <!-- Those Bindings work fine -->
          <Grid Height="20"
                Width="80"
                Margin="{Binding Margin}">
            <Grid.Background>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="Orange" />
            </Grid.Background>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

      <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
          <!-- This line only works with static numbers (0,1,2) and 
                 changes the Column of all Elements -->
          <Setter Property="Grid.Column"
                  Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}" />
        </Style>   
      </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
  </Grid>
```

**Code**

```
public partial class BindGridColumns : Window {
    private ObservableCollection<object> ItemsList;

    public BindGridColumns() {
      InitializeComponent();

      ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<object>();

      for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
      {
        ItemsList.Add(new
       {
         Index = i,
         Margin = new Thickness(0, 60 * i, 0, 0),
         ColumnIndex = ColumnIndex(i),
       });
      }

      this.DataContext = ItemsList;
    }

    private int ColumnIndex(int i) {
      //Purpose: Place every third item the third column
      if (i % 3 == 0) return 2;
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

**Result**

[image]

Since you are not seeing the column binding, verify that you are not getting any binding errors.

Look in the Visual Studio Output window for binding errors.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your help. I kind of don't get the same results you get and the output window does not show any binding errors. Is there anything else that could make that fail? I even copied and pasted your code one by one inside the code behind file and xaml - the only diffrence was that I gave the ItemsControl a Name and set the DataContext of that ItemsControl from the CodeBehind-File ... I really don't know what the issue is... Again thank you very much!

Comment: Did the my code work for you?  Or are you still not seeing the column binding?

Comment: Your code unfortunately did not work for me, too. Thats strange. I am still not seeing the column binding.

Comment: I've just tried that and no, it does not work on a test Project either ... It again only works with concrete numbers but noz with the binding

Comment: What version of Visual Studio and .NET are you using?

Comment: Sorry for that rather late answer. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional and my command promt says: Microsoft (R) .NET CLR Version Tool  Version 4.0.30319.18020
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Versions installed on the machine:
v2.0.50727
v4.0.30319

Comment: Same versions here. , if you create a simple project, and my example code doesn't work then I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks no Problem I guess. THank you very much for your help though :)